# Json object from power shell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to create JSON object from power shell

```
$var6 = '{
    "key5":  "value5",
    "key4":  [
                "$Version"
             ],
    "key1":  "value1",
    "key3":  "value3"
    "key6":  {
                "$Version2"
             },
    "key2":  "value2"
}'
```

I am unable to include these two strings in the JSON

```
Version: "value1","value2","value3"
Version2: "value3","key1":  "value1", "key2":  "value2"
```

how to format by using string itself for the required JSON object

Comment: Really not clear from what you posted what you are trying to do.  BTW, you may want to look into ConvertTo-Json and ConvertFrom-Json.

Comment: @Zoredache is correct; you should look at ConvertTo-Json. Also, string creation using multiple lines will only work with the here-string technique, as described at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7#here-strings.